# How to use my own user chrome profile to open a browser that already logged in Facebook?

Tags: python

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/Users/yuzhipeng/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/yuzhipeng/Downloads/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(a)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

This is my code, however it did not work.

Comment: What was the error that you received?

Comment: There is no error. The opened browser did not log in